# Как настроить bitbucket совместно с github?

Tags: git, github, bitbucket, git-push

У меня на macOS настроен github для push. Но мне нужно сделать push на bitbucket я создал там удаленный репозиторий, клонировал его в свой проект

```
remote add origin git@bitbucket.org:xxx
```

> fatal: remote origin already exists.

```
git push origin master
```

> Permission denied (publickey).
> fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
>
> Please make sure you have the correct access rights
> and the repository exists.

Как его правильно настроить ? C github у меня все работает.

Comment: придусайте другое название для bitbcuket раз `origin` у вас занято для github. Например, `remote add bitbucket git@bitbucket.org:xxx`.

Comment: А потом `git push bitbucket master`. Ну и с правами у вас тоже проблема, как написали в ответе..

Comment: А вообще у вас проблема с ssh ключами..

Answer (score 2):

Я уверен что проблема в том, что у тебя указан логин и пароль в конфигурации `Git` от `github`, а нужно от `bitbucket`.
Поэтому он выдает тебе `Permission denied`

Изменить можно вот так:

`git config --global user.name "myusername"`

в любом случае проблема именно в этом.

Comment: Так тогда у меня c github будет проблема если я поменяю git --global ,или нет?

Comment: одинаковые логин и пароль для обоих репозиториев может быть?

Comment: Нет не будет, у меня два проекта один на git другой на butbucket, я просто меняю юзеров и все окей.

Comment: pavlofff все может быть, я описал ситуацию при которой я получал такую же ошибку, и как я её решал. А значит возможно это будет полезно и автору.

Comment: А как-то локально можно настроить для проекта, чтоб не менять пользователя каждый раз?

Comment: Я думаю если бы это были разные директории то да.  А так как у тебя одна директория то у меня идей нет. Может кто другой поможет.